# Having multiple JPanel's in JFrame with background?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have the following code:

```
public void init() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setIconImage(ResourceUtility.getImage("logo.png").getImage());
    final JPanel container = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(logo, getWidth() / 2 - logo.getWidth(null) / 2, getHeight() - (int) (getHeight() * 0.90), null);
        }
    };
    container.setBackground(UIConfiguration.ColorRedDark);
    add(container);

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setMaximumSize(UIConfiguration.screenSize);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Now, when I try to add another JPanel under it, it loses the background plus the image. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to add a panel _under_ the `container` (therefore making `conatainer` like an overlay)? Please elaborate. You don't have much context in your description. If you mean _under_ position-wise, then you must consider that call `add` with the default BorderLayout will add the CENTER, if position is not specified. So when you `add` another, it kicks out the `container`. If you want a second panel below it, use `add(secondPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END)`

Comment: Start by setting the `container` as the frames `contentPane`, then set a layout manager to the frame, then add what ever you want to it

Comment: @peeskillet Yes, my bad. That is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Whenever I try to add another JPanel above the background it loses its color.

Comment: If you're trying to add another panel on _top_ of/to the `container`, then you need to make sure you `setOpaque(false)` on the second panel. Please post the attempt at adding this _"second JPanel"_ to give us a clearer picture

Comment: In the context of this current code, adding a panel to `container` should not cover the `container` though, since the default FlowLayout will not stretch the second panel to cover the `container`.

Comment: For better help, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. Also make sure to override `getPreferredSize` of the `container`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `panel.setOpaque(false)` for set no background on child `JPanel` objects.

Answer (score 1):

What looks to be your problem is that `container` is locally scoped in the `init` method. So you can't access it (not without some component searching of the frame) to add other components to (which is what you *want* to do).

You are probably trying to add other components to the frame, thinking that this will add them to `container`. Once you add another component to the frame by just doing `add(secondPanel)`. What this basically does (with the frame BorderLayout) is `add(secondPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER)`, implicitly. But you have already done `add(container)`, which is the same as `add(container, BorderLayout.CENTER)`, and each position can only have one component. So the `conatiner` is kicked out, leaving only the `secondPanel`

So a simple fix would just be to take the `container` declaration out of the `init` method, and add components to the `container`

Also keep in mind that JPanels are opaque by default, so adding a JPanel to `container` will cause the JPanels background to cover up the `container` background. So if you want to and a JPanel to the `container`, make sure to `setOpaque(false)` on the JPanel.